# How to reference variables in a map, before the whole map is defined?

Tags: dictionary, sass

I’ll start with my code, as it should be easier to understand what I want to do:

```
@function get-color($color, $lightness) {
  @return map-get(map-get($colors, $color), $lightness);
}

$colors: (
  green: (
    light: #A4EDE1,
    mid: darken(get-color(green, light), 20%),
    dark: darken(get-color(green, mid), 20%)
  ),

  red: (
    light: complement(get-color(green, light)),
    mid: complement(get-color(green, mid)),
    dark: complement(get-color(green, dark))
  )
);
```

As you can see, I have created a multidimensional map, with my color values.
At the moment, I want to create the other colors, through the `darken()` and the `complement()` functions. 
The problem with that is, that I need to reference variables inside of the `$colors` variable, before it is completely filled. This results in an error for my `get-color()` function, which tells me, there is no `$colors` variable.

I know it would be possible to alter the colors outside of my `$colors` map, but the benefit of doing it this way is, that I can always come back and define color values, that are not generated. This would be a huge benefit in maintaining the project.

So here my question: Is there any way to reference another variable in map, before the whole map is defined?

Answer (score 2):

No.  The mapping isn't defined until you reach that semicolon at the end.  So you cannot reference any portion of it until then.

```
$base-color: #A4EDE1;
$colors: (
  green: (
    light: $base-color,
    mid: darken($base-color, 20%),
    dark: darken($base-color, 40%)
  ),
);

$colors: map-merge($colors, (
  red: (
    light: complement(get-color(green, light)),
    mid: complement(get-color(green, mid)),
    dark: complement(get-color(green, dark))
  )));

.foo {
  color: get-color(red, mid);
}
```

Unless you're looping over the mapping, I would recommend *not* using mappings to store your color variables.  Rather, it would be better to simply write a function that will do the manipulation for you:

```
$base-color: #A4EDE1;

@function get-color($lightness, $variation: null, $color: $base-color) {
  $color: if($variation, call($variation, $color), $color);

  @if $lightness == medium {
    @return darken($color, 20%);
  } @else if $lightness == dark {
    @return darken($color, 40%);
  }
  @return $color;
}

.foo {
  color: get-color(mid);
  border: 1px solid get-color(mid, complement);
}
```