# Sass - List maps

Tags: list, dictionary, sass, maps

I need your help... I'm learning to use sass list maps... I have a list map containing key: value pairs for listing hex color codes. I want to use these hex codes into another list map, where I have different lighten() and darken() functions to calculate shades.
Basically, if in the first listmap I have

```
$flat-colors: (
  lizard : ‪#‎16a085‬
);
```

and in the second list map I have

```
$palettes: (
  meadow: (
    xtra-light : lighten(lizard, 60%),
    light : lighten(lizard, 40%),
    mid-light : lighten(lizard, 20%),
    base : lizard,
    mid-dark : darken(lizard, 20%),
    dark : darken(lizard, 40%),
    xtra-dark : darken(lizard, 60%),
  )
);
```

I have a function to return a shade that default to 'base'...

```
@function palette($palette, $tone: 'base') {
  @return map-get(map-get($palettes, $palette), $tone);
}
```

This throws me this error:
    $color: "lizard" is not a color for `lighten'
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try ... `xtra-light : lighten(map-get(lizard, $flat-colors), 60%)`, this way you are pulling the color as palettes is created.  At that point, it has no value for lizard.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583055/how-to-reference-variables-in-a-map-before-the-whole-map-is-defined

Comment: Backwards ... map-get($flat-colors, lizard)

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what it says:  (the string) lizard is not a color.  To reference the color in your mapping, you need to use map-get:

```
$palettes: (
  meadow: (
    xtra-light : lighten(map-get($flat-colors, lizard), 60%)
    // etc
  )
);
```

Comment: @rfornal If you wanted to answer the question, you should have posted an answer instead of wasting your time with comments.  Also, if I had wasted my time copying your "answer", it would have been wrong.

Comment: Despite my previous comment, it is a good answer.  However, I dropped the code into a codepen and actually couldn't get it to work.  Have you tested this?  Maybe it's my settings in codepen, but I thought I'd pass it on.

Comment: Tested. Works fine, obviously.