# how to reference a property inside of a map object

Tags: sass, maps

I have a map of colors, and would like to define subsequent colors in the map based on colors defined earlier within the map.

```
$colors: (
    primary: #184770, 
    secondary: #0969A2, 
    white: #fff, 
    black: #000, 
    green: #24b206, 
    blue: #428bca, 
    purple: #813c8e, 
    grey: (lighten( black, 25%)), 
    grey-light: (lighten( black, 35%)), 
    grey-dark: (lighten( black, 15%))      
);
```

I would like to specify `grey`, `grey-light` and `grey-dark` based on `map-get($colors, black)`.

The example above works only because it references inherent color "black" rather than `map-get($colors, black)`

Can you reference a property inside the same map object?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot reference a map's property inside the same map object. The map is not truly defined until the semi-colon is reached, so before that point, its own properties are unavailable to refer to. Here's a similar existing [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583055/how-to-reference-variables-in-a-map-before-the-whole-map-is-defined).

If you want to add subsequent values based on initially defined values, one route is with a combination of the `map-get` and `map-merge` functions:

```
$base-colors: ( 
  black: #000
);

$extended-colors: (
  grey:       lighten(map-get($base-colors, black), 25%),
  grey-light: lighten(map-get($base-colors, black), 35%),
  grey-dark:  lighten(map-get($base-colors, black), 15%)
);

$colors: map-merge($base-colors, $extended-colors);
```

Note: `map-merge` performs a shallow merge that is best for flat one-dimensional maps; if you are dealing with merging deeper multidimensional maps, you may want to define and use a [recursive function](https://medium.com/@pentzzsolt/a-non-destructive-map-merge-function-for-sass-f91637f87b2e) rather than `map-merge`.